# jQuery Doesn't work when product loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery is working fine when Open page. but, jQuery Doesn't work when product loaded(change) via AJAX. I have used **jquery-1.7.1.min.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $screensize = $(window).width();
    if ($screensize > 1199) {
        $('#content .product-grid > div:nth-child(3n)').after('<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></span>');
    }
    if ($screensize < 1199) {
        $('#content .product-grid > div:nth-child(3n)').after('<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-md-block"></span>');
    }
    if ($screensize < 991) {
        $('#content .product-grid > div:nth-child(3n)').after('<span class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-sm-block"></span>');
    }
});
```

How can I fix it?

I have try following code. So, It is working. but, sometime is not work.

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete ready', function(){
  // FUNCTION CODE
});
```

Comment: You need to call snippet on `success` ajax callback, once elements are added to the DOM: `$.ajax({success: resizeMethod,...});` And to call on document ready: `$(resizeMethod);`. Where `resizeMethod` is the method wrapping your snippet (minus ready hanlder)

Comment: Well, your function is called when the document ready. You have to call it also when you change the page

Comment: @A.Wolff I think you mean `$(document).ready(resizeMethod);` instead of `$(resizeMethod);`

Comment: @RuubW `$(resizeMethod);` is the shorthand way for the same thing

Comment: @wonderb0lt I have try but, I have not success.

Answer (score 2):

Make a method and call it when the DOM is loaded AND AJAX is done.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var resizeMe = function () {
  $screensize = $(window).width();
  ... Do what you want here
}; 

$.ajax({...}).done( function () { resizeMe(); } );

resizeMe();
});
```

Comment: I have try this but, not work for me. any other suggestion please. Thanks.